# Nested wx.PyValidators Decorator Pattern

Tags: python, oop, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am working with [wxPython's validators](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/validator_overview.html). I have a text field that I would like to only accept numbers, and to be required (not left blank.) A quick way to do this would be to simply create one validator class that does both things, however, I would like to make use of the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and use two separate, cohesive validators. That way I can have reusable validator classes that I can mix and match throughout my application.

For example, I want to be able to assign validators like this:

```
requiredAndDigitsOnly = DigitValidator(RequiredValidator(CustomValidator()))
textField = wx.TextCtrl(sbSizer.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY,\
    wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,\
    validator=requiredAndDigitsOnly)
```

**I'm running into this problem:** When I try to use more than one decorator (see code below,) the calls to `self.GetWindow()` return `None`, and so validation stops because it cannot get a handle to the window that is being validated. It must be because `toBeValidated` is not pointing to the right window. **How can I use nested validators with wx.PyValidator?**

This works: `RequiredValidator(CustomValidator())` but this does not: `DigitValidator(RequiredValidator(CustomValidator()))`

`Custom Validator` is a subclass of `wx.PyValidator`:

```
import wx

class CustomValidator(wx.PyValidator):
    ''' 
    This is a basic validator that inherits from
    PyValidator.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomValidator, self).__init__()

    def Clone(self):
        # Every validator must implement a Clone method.
        return CustomValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        return True
    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        return True
```

`RequiredValidator` and `DigitValidator` are subclasses of a base decorator class. Here is what `RequiredValidator` might look like (`DigitValidator` would be pretty much the same, except handle validation differently):

```
class RequiredValidator(ValidatorDecorator):

    def __init__(self, toBeDecorated):
        super(RequiredValidator, self).__init__(toBeDecorated)
        # Now add customization to the validator.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.onClick)

    def Clone(self):
        # Every validator must implement a Clone method.
        return self.__class__(self.toBeDecorated)

    def Validate(self, win):
        textControl = self.GetWindow()
        value = textControl.GetValue()

        if not len(value):
            textControl.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFAC5')
            return False
        return super(RequiredValidator, self).Validate(win)

    def onClick(self, event):
        # ...
```

And finally, the base decorator class might look like this:

```
class ValidatorDecorator(wx.PyValidator):
    '''
        Abstract decorator class
    '''
    def __init__(self, toBeDecorated):
        self.toBeDecorated = toBeDecorated
        super(ValidatorDecorator, self).__init__()

    def Clone(self):
        # Every validator must implement a Clone method.
        return self.toBeDecorated.Clone()

    def Validate(self, win):
        # Delegate this.
        return self.toBeDecorated.Validate(win)

    def GetWindow(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self).GetWindow()

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        # Delegate this.
        return self.toBeDecorated.TransferToWindow()

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        # Delegate this.
        return self.toBeDecorated.TransferFromWindow()
```